# custom page layout not working for me.Need help

Tags: page-layout

I have created this custom layout below:
But the middle row (which is a div side by side ) doesn't stick under the header(top left and top right)
THe header has a white space below it and just pushes the middle row down.
I want to have

top left top right
and then under it just have the middle row with 2 divs side by side.

It seems i'm missing something any advice will be appreciated

```
<div id="s-home">
        <div id="s-home-header-row">
            <!-- Top Row -->
            <div id="s-home-header">
                <!-- Top Left -->
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Top Left" ID="Header" FrameType="None"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
            </div>
            <div id="s-home-topright">
                <!-- Top Right -->
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Top Right" ID="TopRight" FrameType="None"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- Middle Row -->
        <div  id="s-home-middle-row">

            <div id="s-home-leftcolumn">
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Middle Left" ID="LeftColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
            </div>
            <div id="s-home-middlecolumn">
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Middle Center" ID="MiddleColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>

           </div>


        </div>

        <div  id="s-home-footer-row">
            <!-- Footer -->
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Footer" ID="Footer" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CSS. Try giving the     s-home-header-row a     margin-bottom or else the     s-home-middle-row a     margin-top. Use browser's F12 to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Murphy but that didn't work.I found the issue to is that i'm adding a script editor (with a yammer feed) that is putting the Middle left and Middle Center columns down . Any ideas how I can have this yammer feed without not having this issue?